# Add item image in SO advanced pdf/html template?

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to add item image next to item in SO. However, when I run it, it said unexpected error please contact your administrator.
I am not sure where I did wrong. The line I added in SO is below. Could someone point me out, thank you very much.

`<td align="center" style="width: 10%;"><img src="${item.item.storedisplayimage}" /></td>`

Answer (score 0):

If your `src` has `&` characters, try this for `src`:

`${item.item.storedisplayimage?replace("&", "&amp;")`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. What do you mean replace "&"? I don't have & in my code.

Comment: Your img src is the url of your image. If the url has '&' characters, replace them with '&amp;'.

Comment: I see, but how to replace it in this case?

Comment: <td align="center" style="width: 10%;"><img src="${item.item.storedisplayimage?replace("&", "&amp;")}" /></td>

You can check the Freemarker documentation if you need more details - https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace.

Comment: I tried it, the template saved, but when I run SO, it still through this error.
The template cannot be printed due to the following errors: Unexpected ErrorPlease contact your administrator.
BTW, is any better way to debug this kind error message? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve the item.storedisplayimage from the SO,
You have to create a customfield on SO line level that stores the URL